# Importing M3U stream in R

Tags: r, signal-processing, http-live-streaming

This is the link for the live audio stream from a VLF receiver

```
http://67.207.143.181/vlf19.m3u
```

I need to know the method for importing this live stream. If R is not suitable for such kind of signal processing, Please to suggest alternatives for processing and visualizing live data.

Comment: Is your question about how to access the stream in real time, or how to process a MP3 file?

Comment: It is kind of both.. and it is not MP3 it is M3U..

Comment: I thought `m3u` was just a container for `mp3`.  Regardless, I'd start with what you've done so far, and focus the question on one or the other aspect.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I need to refine the question ?

Comment: Yes.  Right now it looks a lot to me like a "here's my problem, please solve it for me" question that's unlikely to get a lot of attention.

Comment: What type of signal processing are you planning on doing? I don't know if it works with live streams, but have you looked at the "seewave" package? It seems to have a lot of [graphical options](http://rug.mnhn.fr/seewave/exam.html) for analyzing sound files.